# Make vscode open the panel on start-up

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

Every time I open vscode I have to click `View->Appearance->Show panel` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open panel with console. Is it possible to run vscode with the panel open by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vscode should remember whether the panel is open or not each time you close the window.  But if it doesn't or you typically have it closed when you exit that vscode window and you have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> each time you open vscode try putting this task into your tasks.json:

```
{
  "label": "open Panel",
  "command": "${command:workbench.action.togglePanel}",
  "type": "shell",
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "runOptions": {"runOn": "folderOpen"}
},
```

Now whenever the workspace opens, the `togglePanel` command will run automatically.